# How to load time-series stock data into quantum amplitude estimation

Tags: qiskit, amplitude-amplification, quantum-computing-for-finance

Now I got some time-series data as showing example below:
[image]

I have spent a period of time realizing the QAE from qiskit, and I found that the tutorial used uncertainty model to reproduce data, while I want it to become my time-series data.

So here's the main question, how should I do to transform it?
Can anyone helps me, please?

Comment: Have you tried to use pandas directly to load your data ?  specifically from a local csv file as for example : 
# pandas.csv_read("https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/aapl.csv", header=0, index_col= 0, names=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], parse_dates=True).

Comment: Qiskit provides data providers for financial data, and one of them is "RandomDataProvider" that generates pseudo-random mock stock-market data. I think that's what you mean when you say "uncertainty model to reproduce data"
I guess you were referring to this notebook:   https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/files/qiskit-tutorials/qiskit/finance/11_time_series.ipynb

Comment: Hi Mensac, I know the data providers you mentioned, but now I just wonder how to transform them into QAE algorithm's input. According to the tutorial, it loads a model called "GaussianConditionalIndependenceModel", and input some parameters to get several random data, which I cannot control.
you can see this link: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/finance/09_credit_risk_analysis.html
Hope you know the answar to my question haha.

Comment: what do you want to use QAE for? what statistic of you data are you trying to get?

Comment: As far as I know, to use QAE you'll have to turn your time series into a probability distribution that you'll need to then turn into a quantum circuit. How you need to transform it will probably deppend on what you want to do.

Comment: Hi CIamar, I wnat to use QAE for credit risk, which is also a package from qiskit finance. 
I'm curious about how to turn my time series into a probability distribution(quantum-circuit), can you elaborate on the process? I hope as detailed as possible, because I'm just a beginner,  thanks a lot.

Comment: I understand you want to turn your time-series into a probability distribution. What do you want this probability distribution to represent? for example, in the tutorial you mentioned they use a distribution that represents the loss of a certain asset. From the date you show you could have a probability distribution of the open, high or low values, por example, or you could want to calculate some other value based on this columns.

Comment: I probably would use "close" value for the distribution, and I want to represent "Value at Risk(VaR)" & "Conditional VaR" to evaluate a certain stock.

Comment: so you want to calculate the VaR and CVaR of the close values of your table if I understand correctly? then you would need to take only that column and turn it into a distribution... maybe this will help you? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13102/how-can-i-load-a-probability-distribution-using-a-quantum-circuit-in-qiskit

Comment: Hi Ciamar, your understanding is correct.
So if I want to calculate VaR & CVaR, I can only enter my data into GaussianConditionalIndependenceModel(according to the official tutorial)?
Or I can use other Models ?

Comment: you can use any model you want from here https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/qiskit.aqua.components.uncertainty_models.html